# R unix terminal pager

Tags: r, readline, less-unix

I'm using R on OS X 10.6 and I prefer the unix console to the R.app for my work. If I issue a help command eg `?print` the help content opens through a pager (i tried `most` and `less`), which however then hides out the content if I exit it bringing me back to the R input line.

What I really want is that the pager output stays on the screen even after I exit it back to R (hitting `q`).

I get this desired behaviour on other Readline-based Cli like `psql` for example, but not on R. Any hints on how this gets configured would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe, e.g. `help(print, help_type="pdf")` or `options(help_type="html"); ?print`.  Is that _helpful_? :-)

Comment: thanks that's definitely helpful :) but what i'm really looking for is a solution to the pager (`less`) issue..

Comment: Have you tried using `-X` with less? E.g., `options(pager="/bin/less -X")` (or wherever OS X puts the `less` binary).

Comment: @Jason, that's the answer to my question there man ! thanks

Comment: Good to hear. I'll make it the answer to the question, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The console pager that R uses can be set with the `options` function. With `less`, the `-X` option suppresses the terminal clearing at exit. So, if the `less` binary is located in `"/bin"` (not sure where it's located in OS X), this should work:

```
> options(pager="/bin/less -X")
```

If you want this to be the default behavior every time you start R, you can place the above command in your `~/.Rprofile` file, which is run automatically at startup.

Alternatively, you can set a `export LESS=-XF` in `~/.bashrc` and this will have an effect across all programs that use less as a pager. The `F` option would further exit straight away if the content is less than a page, which I find quite useful.

Comment: For some reason, it works for help pages only. Can the same be applied to variables output? I remember Octave is used to redirect output to pager if it won't fit the screen. Is it possible in R?

Comment: `df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 3))  <br/>                            
page(df, method = "print")`

Comment: Not working for me when adding an option to 'less' command.  /bin/less -X: not found
Warning message:
error in running command